# Regular expressions as a part of SQL schema

Tags: sql, regex, database, schema

Let's imagine I have a relational database in which, among other things, I want to store employee names and their identification strings. The format of the identification string is strictly defined: it's three upper-case alphabetical characters, followed by a dash, followed by a four-digit number.

Question: does any relational database allow to define a regular expression that a particular textual field must conform to? Like in my example, it would be nice to make the database check all the values of employee ids against a simple regex, rather than do it on the UI level.

Another question: if I'm having problems like this (i.e. necessity to validate field values against an additional set of constraints), does it mean that my schema is denormalized and I should fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to your second question, it depends. (Of course it depends. It always depends.) If you always use your Employee Identification strings as a single “whole” value, then it's normalized. If you find that you are constantly breaking them into the “first and second” parts (3 characters, 4 digits), then you are breaking first normal form. (Roughly, you have two facts in one column, and should split them into their own columns.)

Assuming proper normalization, to my mind the fact that you have to rely on the database to ensure the data is in proper form raises questions about the integrity of your data sources. Why is the data not checked, cleansed, and put in proper formed *before* it is passed to the database? RDBMSes are really good at storing, sorting, and retrieving data, but they’re not so hot at processing complex algorithms. it's just not what they’re for. You can do it in the database, yes, but there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with a check constraint.

- [PostgreSQL Check Constraint Supports Regular Expressions](http://joseph.randomnetworks.com/2004/05/24/postgresql-check-constraint-supports-regular-expressions/)

Obviously support for this varies between vendors. Some databases have limited or no support for regular expressions, and some don't support check constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the checking via a constraing on the field.  It depends on which database you are using.  In SQL Server, you might have to use syntax such as:

```
check (len(EmpId) = 7 and left(EmpId, 3) between 'AAA' and 'ZZZ' and
       substring(EmpId, 4) = '-' and isnumeric(right(EmpId, 4)) = 1
```

First, the check constraint goes into the table creation, preceded by a "CONSTRAINT  statement.

Second, regular expressions would be a cleaner way to do this.  But, not all databases support them.

Third, the above isn't perfect.  For instance, it allows 'B1B' for the first three characters.  More complicated logic can fix that.

And finally, to guarantee upper case, you may need to set the collation for the comparison to be case sensitive.